# Unable to export a python chainladder triangle to excel sheet

Tags: python

I am exploring the `chainladder` package. I tried to export a triangle structure into an excel sheet. But it throws an error. Has anyone ever faced this kind of problem. I am using chainladder==0.7.9 with pandas==0.24.2. Here is my simple code by reading their documentation https://chainladder-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/index.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import chainladder as cl
raa = cl.load_sample('raa')
cl.load_template('triangle', triangle=raa.latest_diagonal).to_excel('raa_example.xlsx')
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\pyworkspace37\chainladderdemo\venv\lib\site-packages\chainladder\utils\exhibits.py in load_template(template, env, **kwargs)
     24     try:
---> 25         return load_yaml(template, env, **kwargs)
     26     except:

e:\pyworkspace37\chainladderdemo\venv\lib\site-packages\xlcompose\templates.py in load_yaml(template, env, str_only, **kwargs)
    108     else:
--> 109         return _make_xlc(yaml.load(template, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader), **kwargs)
    110 

e:\pyworkspace37\chainladderdemo\venv\lib\site-packages\xlcompose\templates.py in _make_xlc(template, **kwargs)
     51                 return core.Tabs(*[('Sheet1', item) for item in tabs])
---> 52         key = list(template.keys())[0]
     53         if key in ['Row', 'Column']:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-270670213d97> in <module>
----> 1 cl.load_template('triangle', triangle=raa.latest_diagonal).to_excel('raa_example.xlsx')
      2 #,type(raa.latest_diagonal)
      3 type(raa_model.ultimate_)

e:\pyworkspace37\chainladderdemo\venv\lib\site-packages\chainladder\utils\exhibits.py in load_template(template, env, **kwargs)
     26     except:
     27         template = os.path.join(path, "templates", template.lower() + ".yaml")
---> 28         return load_yaml(template, env, **kwargs)

e:\pyworkspace37\chainladderdemo\venv\lib\site-packages\xlcompose\templates.py in load_yaml(template, env, str_only, **kwargs)
    107         return template
    108     else:
--> 109         return _make_xlc(yaml.load(template, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader), **kwargs)
    110 
    111 def load_json(template, env=None, **kwargs):

e:\pyworkspace37\chainladderdemo\venv\lib\site-packages\xlcompose\templates.py in _make_xlc(template, **kwargs)
     50             except:
     51                 return core.Tabs(*[('Sheet1', item) for item in tabs])
---> 52         key = list(template.keys())[0]
     53         if key in ['Row', 'Column']:
     54             return getattr(core, key)(*[_make_xlc(element, **kwargs)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Please let me know if I am missing something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load_template` is used to load a YAML template containing the specs for your Excel file. This particular template file is designed to create a standard exhibit for regular triangles, not diagonals.  Templates are used to contain complex layouts, formatting, logic.

This should resolve the issue:

```py
cl.load_template('triangle', triangle=raa).to_excel('raa_example.xlsx')
```

If you would simply like to export just the diagonal to Excel, you can do so without a template:

```
raa.latest_diagonal.to_excel('raa_example.xlsx')
# or
cl.DataFrame(raa.latest_diagonal).to_excel('raa_example.xlsx')
```